# How can i decipher a line of code in ascii?

Tags: c#, ascii, minecraft, launcher

i was wondering to now why im getting a line like this

`MojangProfiles.\u003C\u003Ec__DisplayClass16_0 cDisplayClass160 = new MojangProfiles.\u003C\u003Ec__DisplayClass16_0();`

This line, is on my MojangProfiles.cs (i don't own this code, but i'm looking at code on github and those things to learn how to use some classes and types in C#).

How can i decompile that? In the next line, i have this

`cDisplayClass160.account = new MinecraftAccount(displayName, accessToken, userid, uuid, username);`

The problem, is that there is not a variable "account" in my MojangProfile, and i dont have any variable with it inside. Any idea?

Here is the whole class: https://pastebin.com/An6szP8c

Comment: Someone used a decompiler to turn IL back into C#, but it didn't do a very good job, and gave you C# which is not valid

Comment: So what should i do?

Comment: You can either fix the C# until it's valid, or throw it away as garbage. Up to you. Fixing it probably requires some knowledge of what the compiler does under the hood when it compiles C#

Comment: So i cant do anything?

Comment: You can do either of the 2 options I mentioned above

Comment: Yeah, but idk what could be happening, i mean, i have tried a lot of things

Comment: On that particular line, the problem is that `<` and `>` (which are what `\u003C` and `\u003E` are) aren't valid characters in a C# type name, so you'll need to rename that type to something valid

Comment: Yeah, but i cant do anything with <> because i dont have lists or something that needs that

Comment: Hmm? I think step 0 here is an understanding of C#, unfortunately. The `<` and `>` don't refer to generics -- they're part of a compiler-generated class name. You need to rename that class so it doesn't have `<` or `>` in it

Comment: Ok, i will take more classes. But please, if you can explain me it, i will apprecciate it

Comment: I did. Twice. It's not clear to me what else I need to explain

Comment: I didnt read that final Comment, im sry. Ty, i will try smth

Comment: As canton7 said, someone did a poor job of converting the IL to C# and you need some knowledge of what the compiler does in order to reconstitute the original code. Plenty of tools are available that are capable of doing better. `<>__DisplayClass...` classes are related to capturing local variables in lambdas. That type is where the local is promoted so that it can be conveyed to the lambda. In this case, the `account` local variable is being captured by the lambda in a `.Any(...)` call.